# Editing CSV using Python

Tags: python, csv

I have a big csv file that I want to edit. The editing here means deleting the columns that have only one value. So far, I wrote this (since I'm a newbie in Python I'm stuck and not sure if that is the right solution for the problem):

```
import csv
import collections
import numpy as np 


number_of_rows = 2432 
interseting_cols = [] 

col_values = collections.defaultdict(list)
col_values_named = collections.defaultdict(list)
new_row = collections.defaultdict(list)
inputFile = open('input.csv', 'r',newline='');
outputFile= open('output.csv','w')

reader = csv.reader(inputFile)
writer = csv.writer(outputFile)
#skip field names
next(reader)
for row in reader:
    for col, value in enumerate(row):
        col_values[col].append(value)
        #each column is now saved col_values ( without the headers )


for  i in range(len(col_values)):
    if len(set(col_values[i][:(number_of_rows-1)])) != 1:
        interseting_cols.append(i)# saved the index of the columns with valid values 

inputFile.seek(0)

# reading the file again now with headers
for row in reader:
    for col, value in enumerate(row):
        col_values_named[col].append(value)# saving the columns now with header 


# generating a new CSV file, only with interessting columns :
for i in range(number_of_rows):
    print("i value ",i)
    for j in range(len(interseting_cols)): # I'm not sure about this PART !!!!
            new_row.append(col_values_named[interseting_cols[j]])
            writer.writerow(new_row)
```

Any idea how to do the last loop? Or is there is a better way to solve this?

**UPDATE**
say the file looks like

```
---------------------------------------------------
            |A|B   |C   |D  |F   |G|H   |I|J  |K   |       
--------------------------------------------------- 
1           |1|NULL|444 |201|0.01|A|NULL|4|9.5|NULL|     
--------------------------------------------------- 
2           |2|NULL|NULL|201|0   |A|NULL|4|9.5|NULL|
--------------------------------------------------- 
3           |4|NULL|444 |201|0   |A|NULL|4|9.5|NULL|
--------------------------------------------------- 
4           |1|NULL|444 |201|0   |A|NULL|4|9.5|NULL|
```

in this case the result should only include only three columns 
**A,C and  F**

Comment: Could you edit the question to include a small sample from your CSV file, and also how you want it to appear afterwards.

Comment: As a tip, there exists a libary called Pandas, which is extremely useful in reading, manipulating und writing data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using pandas library, you can reduce all your extra work by its own inbuilt functions. Here is a small implementation of the requirement you posted above. If you are a beginner and in need of little more clear explanations, ping me in comment and am ready to give a little more information. By the way, start playing around with pandas.

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv('input.csv')

for columns in df:
    if len(df[columns].unique()) == 1:
        df.drop(columns, 1, inplace=True)

df.to_csv('output.csv', index=None)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but how can I ignore the  headers  in the 1st rows ?

Comment: While writing to csv?? just do **df.to_csv('output.csv', index=None, header=False)**

Comment: no while reading because if the check includes the headers , it will never delete any column

Comment: I've tried df.next() to avoid the first row, but it isn't working !

Comment: Sorry for the late reply bro.! while reading, just do this.. **df = pd.read_csv('input.csv', header = None )**

Comment: thanks for replying I've solved it, but using the hardway no panda ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Unless the spreadsheet is truly enormous, just read the whole thing in and then find what you want!

Untested code:

```
headers = reader.next()
sheet = []
for row in reader:
    sheet.append(row)

# assuming all rows are the same length ...
for colno,header in enumerate(headers):
    col = [ row[colno] for row in sheet ]
    distinct = set( col)
    if len(distinct) > 1:
        # col contains at least two distinct values, so
        # do something with it and its header and/or column number
        writer.writerow(  [header, colno] + col )
```